# Showing Sigma an Converges

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a_n$ be a sequence of real numbers such that $a_n ≥ 0$  $∀  n \in \mathbb{N}$. Show that  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{1+an}$ converges.

[Solution Attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5fVH.png)

Comment: Please don't use links; add your attempt to the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

Well the one direction is obvious, by the comparison test: it is $a_n\geq0$, hence $\frac{1}{1+a_n}\leq1$, therefore $\frac{a_n}{1+a_n}\leq a_n$. So if $\Sigma_na_n$ converges, so does $\Sigma\frac{a_n}{1+a_n}$. Now for the other direction, use the comparison test: suppose that $\Sigma\frac{a_n}{1+a_n}$ converges. then $a_n/(1+a_n)\to0$. you can easily see that this implies that $a_n\to0$; I leave this as an easy exercise. Then $$\frac{\frac{a_n}{1+a_n}}{a_n}=\frac{1}{1+a_n}\to1\in(0,\infty)$$ therefore both the series converge or diverge; since the one is convergent, so is the other.